# input.next() for one line with multiple values

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I'm writing an adres directly from my code to a file with filewriter and those values are stored on one line in the file example(street 264, Washington). Now I want to write that adres to a new Arraylist with a constructor that asks for three input values(street, number, city)

I have accomplished it this way but when I input a street like "Park Avenue" it gives an error as Park avenue is two words... also wondering if there is a faster "better" way:

```
@Override
public List<Adres> query(ISpecification specification) {
    File adresConnection = new File(fsConnection.getAdresConnection());
    if (specification instanceof FileSpecification) {
        if (((FileSpecification) specification).toFileQuery().equals("ALL")) {
            ArrayList<Adres> adressen = new ArrayList<>();
            try (
                    Scanner input = new Scanner(adresConnection)) {
                System.out.println("Adressen laden wordt uitgevoerd");

                while (input.hasNext()) {
                    String straat = input.next();
                    String huisNrMetKomma = input.next();
                    int huisNummer = Integer.parseInt(huisNrMetKomma.substring(0, huisNrMetKomma.length() - 1));
                    String plaats = input.next();

                    adressen.add(new Adres(straat, huisNummer, plaats));
                }
```

Comment: Read entire line using `nextLine` method and then parse it (it would be difficult if you dont have standard address line).

Comment: @SMA, you mean if the address is not restricted to a certain length? Could you give an example of how to parse it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nextLine reads multiple words so try using nextLine(); instead of next();

```
while (input.hasNext()) {
                String straat = input.nextLine();
                String huisNrMetKomma = input.nextLine();
                int huisNummer = Integer.parseInt(huisNrMetKomma.substring(0, huisNrMetKomma.length() - 1));
                String plaats = input.nextLine();

                adressen.add(new Adres(straat, huisNummer, plaats));
            }
```

Comment: that would have worked would it not be that the address is written on one line in the file, so nextLine would mean it reads the entire address in the first String already. And not in three seperate Strings.